# Does React discard queued events on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, dom-events

I'm making a React form component with simple validation. Each field is validated on blur and the form has a simple `onSubmit` function. A boolean is stored in state as to whether the field should show an error message, and this is updated during validation.

Everything works fine except when the `onBlur` of a field, and the `onSubmit of the form are triggered at the same time. i.e. I type something in a field and immediately click the submit button.

The `onBlur` is executed first, and if no change to validation state happens then `onSubmit` is executed as expected. However, if `onBlur` changes the state, then the `onSubmit` function ***is never called***.

So my question is; does setting state in a component clear any queued events and are there any possible solutions to this problem?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);

        this.state = { shouldShowError: false }
    }

    handleBlur(event) {
        console.log("blur")

        const isEmpty = event.target.value === ""

        this.setState({ shouldShowError: isEmpty })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        console.log("submit")
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            < form onSubmit = { this.handleSubmit} >
                < input type = "text" onBlur = { this.handleBlur } /> 
                { this.state.shouldShowError ? < p > This field is required. < /p> : null } 
                < button type = "submit" > Submit < /button > 
            < /form>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(< SimpleForm / >, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0mll0yd/2r9ua1n1/2/) which should allow you to see the error for yourself. Any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Manolo for confirming my suspicions that it is the state change which wipes the event queue. I think I've found a solution that will do for now:

If you need both the onBlur and onSubmit body to execute, you can wrap the onBlur body in a setTimeout so that it is put on the task queue and executed after onSubmit:

```
handleBlur(event) {
    const value = event.target.value

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("blur")

        const isEmpty = value === ""

        this.setState({ shouldShowError: isEmpty }) 
    }, 10)
}
```

Note that in react, you cannot by default access the event asynchronously so you will need to either extract the values you need outside of the timeout, or call event.persist().

I do not need the onBlur body to execute as my onSubmit validates the form as well. After a bit of reading, I found out you can call event.relatedTarget to access the component that focus was shifted to. So I can check if it is the submit button and only execute the onBlur body if it isn't:

```
handleBlur(event) {
    if (!event.relatedTarget || event.relatedTarget.id !== 'submit') {
        console.log("blur")

        const isEmpty = event.target.value === ""

        this.setState({ shouldShowError: isEmpty }) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing the state in a component clear any queued events, because the state change causes that the entire component will be *re-rendered*, and the events will be cleared and *re-attached*.

I would make the validation in the submit event callback, instead of blur one. If you want to validate while user is typing, you could use `onKeyUp`.

If you want to preserve your example behaviour, you could submit the form inside `onBlur` callback when the error was showing and there is no error:

```
class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);

        this.state = { shouldShowError: false }
    }

    handleBlur(event) {
        console.log("blur")

        const isShowingError = this.state.shouldShowError;
        const isEmpty = event.target.value === ""

        if (isShowingError && !isEmpty) {
          console.log("submit the form");
        }
        this.setState({ shouldShowError: isEmpty })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        console.log("submit")
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
          < form onSubmit = { this.handleSubmit} >
                < input type = "text" onBlur = { this.handleBlur } /> 
                { this.state.shouldShowError ? < p > This field is required. < /p> : null } 
                < button type = "submit" > Submit < /button > 
            < /form>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(< SimpleForm / >, document.getElementById('container'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2r9ua1n1/3/

Comment: Well I'm glad that is the case and it isn't just me going insane. With regards to your suggestion, part of the requirements is to have validation on blur, as onKeyUp or onChange would prematurely show error messages for an email field. Also, there are 8 fields in the form, so having validation only on submit is not particularly user friendly.

Comment: But then, you don't need to submit the form when validation fails, and if state doesn't change on blur when submitting the form, the form will be submitted (the submit event callback will be executed).

Comment: That is true. The problem occurs specifically when the field's error message is showing, the user corrects it and then clicks submit. In this scenario, the form should submit because the form is valid but it does not as the state change in the onBlur is cancelling the onSubmit event.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do your newest suggestion either. The form should only submit when the submit button itself is clicked.